# Making a large lookup table in openGLES on IOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am using openGLES on IOS to do some general data processing. Currently I am trying to make a large lookup table (~1M elements) of float values accessed by integer indexes, and I would like it to be 1D (though 2D works). I have learnt that using texture/sampler is probably the way to do that, but my remaining questions are:

1. Sampler or Texture, which is more efficient? What would be the parameter settings to achieve the optimal results (like those configured in glTexParameteri())?
2. I know I can use 1-sample-high 2D sampler/texture as 1D, but being out of curiosity, I wonder if the 1D sampler/texture is removed on IOS es3? I cannot find the method glTexImage2D() nor parameters GL_TEXTURE_1D with ES3/gl.h imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL ES does not have 1D textures. Never did in any previous version, and still doesn't up to the most recent version (3.2). And I very much doubt it ever will.

At least in my opinion, that's no big loss. You can do anything you could have done with a 1D texture using a 2D texture of height 1. The only minor inconvenience is that you have to pass in some more sampling attributes, and a second texture coordinate when you sample the texture in your GLSL code.

For the sizes you're looking at, you'll have the same problem with a 2D texture of height 1 that you would have faced with 1D textures as well: You're limited by the maximum texture size. This is given by the value you can query with `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, ...)`. Typical values for relatively recent mobile platforms are 2K to 8K. Based on the [published docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html), it looks like the limit is 4096 on recent Apple platforms (A7 to A9).

There is nothing I can think of that would give you a much larger range in a single dimension. There is a [EXT_texture_buffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_buffer.txt) extension that targets your use case, but I don't see it in the list of supported extensions for iOS.

So the best you can probably do is store the data in a 2D texture, and use div/mod arithmetic to split your large 1D index into 2 texture coordinates.

Comment: "You can do anything you could have done with a 1D texture using a 2D texture of height 1." Except have 1D array textures, of course. Even if you could turn off blending in the height axis of a 2D texture, mipmapping still won't work.

Comment: Thanks Reto, that explained a lot! One more question if you would not mind, what would be the best way to configure the texture to optimize performance as I am using all-integer indexes? As much as I have learnt, the texture is designed to be fetched with non-integer indexes and it will be interpolated or rounded, which I can skip.

Comment: Never mind Reto, I tried out texelFetch and it worked.